# Log in fails after installing additional drivers

Tags: drivers, updates, login-screen

So I updated my graphic drivers using the additional drivers option and restarted my computer upon completion.

Now when I try to log in everything looks fine, I put in my password and hit enter, what comes up next is the screen with one(1) distorted icon on the desktop, and the background, nothing more.

How can I revert back to the default graphic drivers so I can boot into Ubuntu again?

Let me know if you need anymore details.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting a previous version of Ubuntu and see if that fixes it.

If this fixes it, run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. Once this is complete open up Update manager and uncheck **ALL** of any updates having to do with graphics, then select one (1 - only one) again and write down the graphic update you selected. 

Install these updates and restart, if you get the same problem, you probably have found the problem. If not, then do this again until (writing down the selected graphics update each time) you get this problem again. Once you find it, boom, you have your offending update and you can look for answers specifically for that update.

Hope this helps!

Comment: no problem! I try to give good help, even though I'm rather n00b myself in some things :D

Comment: Just a follow up to say that this did not work and I am still looking for ideas.